# Extra column added to DataGridView for selection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is my first `WinForm` app and I am binding `DataTable` to it. `DataGridView` looks like

[image]

I don't need extra column added in top left corner.

I have already tried to find solution on Google but none helped.

Please suggest.

Comment: Means you don't want column 149396...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `RowHeadersVisible` to false for the `DataGridView`.

```
MyDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Answer is correct, but `DataGridView` is different control then `DataGrid`.

Comment: Sorry, comment was confused. Link was correct. Just change datagrid to datsgridview